# Cannot insert a object into a database from an array in angular2/meteor

Tags: angular, meteor, typescript

I'm trying to do the Angular2/Meteor tutorial using my own type 'class' instead of 'party' and I'm getting errors on this line of code

```
classes.forEach((class: Class) => Classes.insert(class));
```

Here's the whole file:

```
import { Classes } from '../../../both/collections/classes.collection';
import { Class } from '../../../both/models/class.model';

export function loadClasses() {
 if (Classes.find().cursor.count() === 0) {
const classes: Class[] = [{
  name: 'Class1',
  teacher: 'Dumbledore',
  location: 'room 101'
}, {
  name: 'Class2',
  teacher: 'Hagrid',
  location: 'Online'
}, {
  name: 'Class3',
  teacher: 'Harry Potter',
  location: 'room 124'
}];

classes.forEach((class: Class) => Classes.insert(class));

 }
```

}

Here is the error code among others that say the same thing for the most part.

server/imports/fixtures/classes.ts (20, 54): Argument of type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Class'.

Not sure if it is just being read wrong and I need to reset something. I have combed through my code multiple times and can't find any syntax/spelling errors. I tried 'meteor reset' just in case but no luck with that.

Comment: so I have this class.model.ts file export interface Class {
  name: string;
  teacher: string;
  location: string;
} is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect Typescript does not like you using the ES6 reserved word `class` (lowercase) as an argument name.

Try replacing it by something else (e.g. `currentClass` or whatever except another reserved word).

Using `Class` (uppercase first letter) as a class or interface name is legal, but for sure it will call for this very mistake of using the reserved word `class` in the wrong place sooner or later.

Comment: Yes the reserved word was the issue, makes it a real pain when making a class planner app haha.

Comment: 5 years later, your answer helped me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the mistake you are doing.
this is the code where you are doing mistake

```
classes.forEach((class: Class) => Classes.insert(class));
```

in this classes.forEach should be apply on a array that you want to insert into database. and inside this loop you want to insert each class into your database table. and you have taken both array name and database collection name as classes which is wrong. how it differentiate ?

try something like this code

```
if (Head.find().cursor.count() === 0) {
      const heads = [
      { head: 'javascript'}, 
      { head: 'angularjs'}
      ];
    heads.forEach((defaulthead) => Head.insert(defaulthead));
  }
```

and i am agree with ghybs answer. you should not use reserved word. Reserved words (like JavaScript keywords) cannot be used as names